# Add new row to DataGridView using textboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to Add from textboxes to datagridview but the code doesn't work

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox6.Text;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = textBox5.Text;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = textBox7.Text;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = dateTimePicker3.Value;
```

Comment: there is a button under the textboxes I want to create a new row when the button pressed, there is no code

Comment: OMG, I did not pay attention to this confusion, by mistake I mixed two question together, sorry for that, now I update it.

Comment: Dear Rama, You can review answers and choose accepted answer and also vote for other answers if they are helpful, this way your question and answers will be more helpful for future readers :) Even If you find your answer yourself, I recommend reviewing posted answers. Also If you find a better answer you can post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest now knowing that you are indeed in a forms project. I see another person has suggested this already, I am adding in assertion so that if any of the TextBox controls are empty the row is not added.

```
if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox6.Text)) || (!!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox5.Text)) || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox7.Text)))
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {textBox6.Text,textBox5.Text,textBox7.Text,dateTimePicker3.Value });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have setup correctly your `DataGridView` columns, you can use the following [DataGridViewRowCollection.Add Method (Object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbs04kbx(v=vs.110).aspx) overload like this

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox6.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox7.Text, dateTimePicker3.Value);
```

Note that the above will work only if the count of the columns in the grid view is the same as the count of the passed values.

Alternatively you can use something like this, which would work for every scenario

```
int rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
var row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
row.Cells[0].Value = textBox6.Text;
row.Cells[1].Value = textBox5.Text;
row.Cells[2].Value = textBox7.Text;
row.Cells[3].Value = dateTimePicker3.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of strings from the textboxes and add this to the datagrid view.

```
string[] row = new string[] { textBox6.Text,textBox5.Text,textBox7.Text,
           dateTimePicker3.Value};
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```